# Charcteristic directions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Well in my assignment I need to find the characterstic directions of a PDE. A characteristic direction is a line along which the function behaves as an ODE.

The problem PDE is:

$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} +\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} + 3\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial y}  = 0$$

It is given that the characteristic equation is of the form:
$$\frac{d}{ds_1} = \frac{\partial }{\partial x} + A \frac{\partial}{\partial y} $$
And I have to find the largest value A.

Now I start by defining the  helper equations:

$$p = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}  \qquad q = \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} $$
$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial y}  = \frac{\partial q}{\partial x}  = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial y} $$

Which then (together with the original equation) give the following two equations

$$ \frac{\partial p}{\partial x}  + \frac{\partial q}{\partial y} + 3\frac{\partial p}{\partial y} = 0$$
$$ \frac{\partial p}{\partial x}  - \frac{\partial q}{\partial y} = 0 $$

Now the charasteric equation is a linear combination of above:
$$\left( \frac{\partial p}{\partial x}  + \frac{\partial q}{\partial y} + 3\frac{\partial p}{\partial y}  \right) +  \alpha \left( \frac{\partial p}{\partial x}  - \frac{\partial q}{\partial y} \right) = 0$$
This can then be rewritten to single out $p$ and $q$:

$$\left( \frac{\partial }{\partial x} + (3-\alpha) \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \right)p + \left( a\frac{\partial}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \right)q$$

I'm stuck there however how can I continu further? I have no idea how to get from this to the answer? I basically now in above equation have to find directions (combinations of x,y) for which the above differential equations becomes an ODE.